# EF Core Code First Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

Im using code first approach in my project. Im trying to create dynamic `Create` action and dynamic `Complete(UnitOfWork)` action as well. Im getting that error after my function adding first value.
Let me show you to my function :

```
   public void WebFairHallSeatingCreator(int webFairHallID)
        {
            int[] hallSeatingOrderColumnValue = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            string[] hallSeatingOrderRowValue = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
            var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();
            for (int row = 0; row < hallSeatingOrderRowValue.Length; row++)
            {                
                for (int col = 1; col <= hallSeatingOrderColumnValue.Length; col++)
                {
                    if ((hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString() == "c") || (hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString() == "d"))
                    {
                        if ((col == 5) || (col == 6) || (col == 7))
                        {
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue = "x";
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = 15;
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue= hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString();
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = col;
                            hallSeatingOrder.WebFairHallID = webFairHallID;
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.Complete();// This is the point

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue = hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString();
                        hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = col;
                        hallSeatingOrder.WebFairHallID = webFairHallID;
                        _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                        _unitOfWorkWFH.Complete();// This is the point

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

here its my `HallSeatingOrder` class :

```
  public class HallSeatingOrder : Base
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int HallSeatingOrderID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int WebFairHallID { get; set; }
        public int? CompanyID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int HallSeatingOrderColumnValue { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string HallSeatingOrderRowValue { get; set; }
        public bool HallSeatingOrderIsSpecial { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public WebFairHall WebFairHall { get; set; }
    }
    public class HallSeatingOrderConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<HallSeatingOrder>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<HallSeatingOrder> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.HallSeatingOrderID);
            builder.HasOne(x => x.Company)
                .WithMany(x => x.HallSeatingOrders)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.CompanyID)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
            builder.HasOne(x => x.WebFairHall)
                .WithMany(x => x.HallSeatingOrders)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.WebFairHallID)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
        }
    }
```

i allready look out of every question with my problem.
i try using `ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` and `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`  but none of it worked on me.

Comment: Don't reuse single entity instance inside a loop for creating multiple entities. This `var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();` should be inside each block which calls `Create`.

Comment: i will try and let u know @IvanStoev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the @IvanStoev, i solve that problem. there is nothing wrong with my model and my configuration. there was a one mistake and let me show u that:

```
public void WebFairHallSeatingCreator(int webFairHallID)
        {
            int[] hallSeatingOrderColumnValue = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
            string[] hallSeatingOrderRowValue = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };

            for (int row = 0; row < hallSeatingOrderRowValue.Length; row++)
            {                
                for (int col = 1; col <= hallSeatingOrderColumnValue.Length; col++)
                {
                    if ((hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString() == "c") || (hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString() == "d"))
                    {
                        if ((col == 5) || (col == 6) || (col == 7))
                        {
                            var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue = "x";
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = 15;
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.Complete();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue= hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString();
                            hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = col;
                            hallSeatingOrder.WebFairHallID = webFairHallID;
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                            _unitOfWorkWFH.Complete();

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();
                        hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderRowValue = hallSeatingOrderRowValue.GetValue(row).ToString();
                        hallSeatingOrder.HallSeatingOrderColumnValue = col;
                        hallSeatingOrder.WebFairHallID = webFairHallID;
                        _unitOfWorkWFH.RepositoryHallSeatingOrder.Create(hallSeatingOrder);
                        _unitOfWorkWFH.Complete();

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

i need to create that   `var hallSeatingOrder = new HallSeatingOrder();` for each of for loop,thats all. ***Thanks to him.***